# "log" is not a graphical parameter' error when using plot()

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot two histograms with a logarithmic x axis in one graph in a shiny app.  Here's the code that's throwing errors:

```
allGeneData <- read.csv('data/CoRN_data1.csv')

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  igsAll <- allGeneData[allGeneData$Gene=="IGS",]
  igsClean <- igsAll[!is.na(igsAll$copies_indiv_fit_avg),]
  igsClean$copies_indiv_fit_avg <- igsClean$copies_indiv_fit_avg + 1
  xmax <- max(igsClean$copies_indiv_fit_avg)*1.1
  ylimits <- seq(0,10)

  varList <- levels(allGeneData$variety)

  selectedVar <- reactive({
    s <- igsClean[igsClean$variety==input$varietySelect,]
    sNumbs <- s$copies_indiv_fit_avg
    sHisto <- hist(sNumbs)
    return(sHisto)
  })
  remainder <- reactive({
    r <- igsClean[igsClean$variety!=input$varietySelect,]
    rNumbs <- r$copies_indiv_fit_avg
    rHisto <- hist(rNumbs)
    return(rHisto)
  })

  output$ggplotHisto2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(selectedVar(), col=rgb(0,1,1,.25), xlim=c(1,xmax), ylim=c(0,12), log="x")
    plot(remainder(), col=rgb(1,1,0,.25), xlim=c(1,xmax), ylim=c(0,12),add=T)
  })
})
```

Here's the error:

> Warning in run(timeoutMs) : "log" is not a graphical parameter

Most of the documentation I read says `log="x"` is how it's done.  Others say it's `logx=T`.  The latter doesn't bring up an error, but it doesn't make the x-axis logarithmic either.  I've been banging my head over this app for many, many hours and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I get the same error using `title` function, did you solve your problem?

Comment: You need to state which function call generates the error.  Is it really thrown by the first call to plot, or is it thrown by one of the calls to hist inside the call to plot?  Also, try to minimize that code to something smaller that produces the same error.  Presumably the 'remainder' function and plot isn't even needed, and varList isn't used.  Strip out all the computation and plot parameters you don't need to demonstrate the error.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify plot(..., log = 'x'), R plots the x axis on the (natural) log scale, but the values you see on the x axis are the un-logged values.

To see an example of how the above statement is true, consider the following example:

```
y = rnorm(3) #Generate 3 random numbers
x = c(2.7,2.7^2,2.7^3) #Approximately equal to 1, 2, 3 on log scale
plot(y~log(x), bg = 'blue', pch =21) #Plot by directly taking log x
par(new=T) #Used to overlay plot
plot(y~x, col ='red', log='x', xaxt = 'n', pch = 2, xlab = "") #Another way to plot where x is on log scale.          
#Remove x axis labels. 

#The two plots are identical
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you specified `log = "x"` again in the added second plot command.

The following triggers the warning:

`plot(1:100, log = "x")
plot((1:100)^2, log = "x", add = TRUE)`

Whereas the following does not, but gives the same plot:

`plot(1:100, log = "x")
plot((1:100)^2, add = TRUE)`